# What is the difference between "mask_mov" and "mask_blend" when using intrinsics / AVX?

Tags: intrinsics, avx512

What is the difference between, say, `_mm512_mask_mov_epi64` and `_mm512_mask_blend_epi64`. Besides the order and name of the arguments I cannot see any difference. Pseudo-code in Intels intrinsics guide looks completely equivalent as well:

Blend:

```
FOR j := 0 to 7
    i := j*64
    IF k[j]
        dst[i+63:i] := b[i+63:i]
    ELSE
        dst[i+63:i] := a[i+63:i]
    FI
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:512] := 0
```

Mov:

```
FOR j := 0 to 7
    i := j*64
    IF k[j]
        dst[i+63:i] := a[i+63:i]
    ELSE
        dst[i+63:i] := src[i+63:i]
    FI
ENDFOR
dst[MAX:512] := 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote two functions plus a `main()` function:

```
#include    <immintrin.h>
#include    <iostream>
#include    <iomanip>

__m512i mov_mask(__m512i & a, __m512i & b)
{
    return _mm512_mask_mov_epi64(a, 0x0F, b);
}

__m512i blend_mask(__m512i & c, __m512i & d)
{
    return _mm512_mask_blend_epi64(0x0F, c, d);
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    __m512i a = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    __m512i b = { 0x21, 0x22, 0x23, 0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28 };
    __m512i c = a;
    __m512i d = b;

    __m512i r = mov_mask(a, b);
    for(int i(0); i < 512 / 64; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
                << "a: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&a)[i]
            << " -- b: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&b)[i]
            << " -- r: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&r)[i]
            << '\n';
    }

    r = blend_mask(c, d);
    for(int i(0); i < 512 / 64; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0')
               << "c: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&c)[i]
            << " -- d: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&d)[i]
            << " -- r: 0x" << std::setw(16) << ((uint64_t*)&r)[i]
            << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I compiled with:

```
g++ -std=gnu++23 -mavx512dq -O3 -o a a.cpp
```

I checked the output of the two functions with

```
objdump -d a | less
```

and it is exactly the same:

```
00000000000015e0 <_Z8mov_maskRDv8_xS0_>:
    15e0:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    15e4:       62 f1 fd 48 6f 0f       vmovdqa64 (%rdi),%zmm1
    15ea:       b8 0f 00 00 00          mov    $0xf,%eax
    15ef:       c5 f9 92 c8             kmovb  %eax,%k1
    15f3:       62 f2 f5 49 64 06       vpblendmq (%rsi),%zmm1,%zmm0{%k1}
    15f9:       c3                      ret

0000000000001600 <_Z10blend_maskRDv8_xS0_>:
    1600:       f3 0f 1e fa             endbr64
    1604:       62 f1 fd 48 6f 0f       vmovdqa64 (%rdi),%zmm1
    160a:       b8 0f 00 00 00          mov    $0xf,%eax
    160f:       c5 f9 92 c8             kmovb  %eax,%k1
    1613:       62 f2 f5 49 64 06       vpblendmq (%rsi),%zmm1,%zmm0{%k1}
    1619:       c3                      ret
```

(I used g++ hence the extra decoration to the function names).

So you are right, they are exactly the same thing (except for the position of the mask in the list of parameters).

---

Since Peter Cordes mentioned `icc` (which is really `icpx` now), I though I could give that a try. It's not even using `VPBLENDMQ` or some `MOV` instruction. It uses the `VSHUFI64X2` instead. Better optimized for sure. Two instead of four instructions (not counting the `ENDBR64` and `RET` instructions).

Compiled with:

```
icpx -mavx512dq -oa ~/tmp/a.cpp
```

Output:

```
00000000004011c0 <_Z8mov_maskRDv8_xS0_>:
  4011c0:       62 f1 fe 48 6f 06       vmovdqu64 (%rsi),%zmm0
  4011c6:       62 f3 fd 48 43 07 e4    vshufi64x2 $0xe4,(%rdi),%zmm0,%zmm0
  4011cd:       c3                      ret    

00000000004011d0 <_Z10blend_maskRDv8_xS0_>:
  4011d0:       62 f1 fe 48 6f 06       vmovdqu64 (%rsi),%zmm0
  4011d6:       62 f3 fd 48 43 07 e4    vshufi64x2 $0xe4,(%rdi),%zmm0,%zmm0
  4011dd:       c3                      ret
```

That being said, again, the two functions are exactly the same, bit for bit.

Comment: So is there any reason why two different functions for the exact same thing exist?

Comment: @PaulAner: There are different asm instructions.  Some compilers that take intrinsics more literally (like classic ICC) might actually generate one vs. the other.  mov can have a memory destination (not in intrinsics but the destination might actually be in memory, not a register.)  On current CPUs in normal cases, mask-blends and merge-masked mov run on any ALU port so there's usually no reason to favour one, IIRC.  Blend supports a broadcast memory source operand.  Another reason to have intrinsics is just because the instructions exist; that's how Intel's normally done it.

Comment: @PaulAner: Perhaps forcing the compiler to overwrite a destination register (thus forcing a copy here it still needs the value) could be a way to influence code-gen if it was doing something sub-optimal in the surrounding code.  There's no *good* or general reason to have two intrinsics, I'm just trying to invent special cases.

Comment: @PeterCordes I tested with the Intel compiler and in a way I think it's worse because they actually emit a completely different instruction. It's very well optimized, though, even without any -O instruction,

Comment: I explicitly mentioned **classic** ICC, not LLVM-based ICPX.  LLVM aggressively rewrites intrinsics to what it thinks is the best shuffle/blend.  i.e. it treats a shuffle intrinsic the same way it treats scalar `+` means a math op, not necessarily an `add` instruction.  This often helpful to spot a trick you missed, but can be very frustrating when it pessimizes your code to more instructions or slower instructions.  Classic ICC is the opposite, often not even constant-folding through intrinsics IIRC.  https://godbolt.org/z/W4aYG565M shows it & MSVC: `vmovdqu64 zmm0{k1}, [rsi]` vs. `vpblendmq`

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah. Interesting. I did not want to spend time installing an old compiler... but I now see that you were correct. I was actually surprised by the fact that even without the `-O3` option, ICPX optimized quite a bit. All of that said, if you want to use a specific instruction, you probably need to write the code in assembly in your own `.S` file and not try intrinsics.

Comment: I don't have MSVC or ICC (or ICX) installed either; that's what Godbolt is for!  If I wanted to force a specific instruction, yeah I'd probably write a whole function in asm, or possible just wrap one instruction using GNU C inline `asm`.  (Which is hard to use correctly in general, but a single instruction as a pure function is what it does naturally.)  Or if targeting Windows, I'd consider using MSVC for that function at least, where I wanted a compiler that takes intrinsics mostly literally.  But maybe GCC or Clang for the non-hand-tuned parts of the code.

Answer (score 0):

_mm512_mask_mov_epi64 intrinsic :
it is used to conditionally move elements from one vector to another based on a mask. It takes three parameters: the destination vector, the mask vector, and the source vector. The elements in the destination vector that correspond to a set bit in the mask vector are replaced with the corresponding elements from the source vector.
example:

```
__m512i dest = ...; // Destination vector
__mmask8 mask = ...; // Mask vector
__m512i src = ...; // Source vector

dest = _mm512_mask_mov_epi64(dest, mask, src);
```

in case of _mm512_mask_blend_epi64 intrinsic is used to blend elements from two vectors based on a mask. It takes three parameters: the mask vector, the first source vector, and the second source vector. The elements in the result vector are selected from the first source vector if the corresponding mask bit is set, otherwise, they are selected from the second source vector.

```
__mmask8 mask = ...; // Mask vector
__m512i src1 = ...; // First source vector
__m512i src2 = ...; // Second source vector

__m512i result = _mm512_mask_blend_epi64(mask, src1, src2);
```

Comment: OK but then what is the difference, or is there none. Feels like you've left that as an exercise to the reader

Comment: It is true that the `VPMOVDQ` would smash or not the destination with whatever is found in the source depending on the mask. However, both intrinsics actually uses the `VPBLENDMQ` instruction in both cases and in exactly the same manner, probably because it's more versatile in this case and allows you to not modify one of the input parameters (more C/C++ like).

Comment: we can say that both are same also as @AlexisWilke said